# How to use a custom js framework to build Vite App?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, vite

I want to create a Vite app for a custom frontend framework named OWL.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@odoo/owl

However, this framework is not available in the options that we get while creating the Vite app.
It has only popular libraries/frameworks like Vue, React, etc.

How to create a Vite app with this custom framework?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Docs](https://github.com/odoo/owl/blob/master/doc/learning/quick_start.md) say *Owl is designed to be used with no tooling at al*. So start a plain javascript project and follow the documentation